# Post Type Not Available In 'screen_options_show_screen' hook/filter

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide the Screen options tab for my custom post type (car_page)
on the admin side of WP:

```
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen','AboutThisCar_RemoveScreenOptions');  

function AboutThisCar_RemoveScreenOptions() {                                  
 // remove "screen options" option                                     
      if ( get_query_var( 'post_type')=== 'car_page')   
         return false;
     }
 return true;  }
```

This works for the post-index page, that lists all the posts, but not on the "Add New" nor "Edit" pages.  I've researched and experimented a lot.  It seems like for the latter 2 pages, that the query string info and and current screen info are not yet initialized at the time the hook fires.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the post type from the current screen works for all the pages:

get_current_screen()->post_type

In context:

```
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen','AboutThisCar_RemoveScreenOptions');  
function AboutThisCar_RemoveScreenOptions() {                                  
 // remove "screen options" option                                     
      if ( get_current_screen()->post_type === 'car_page')   // UPDATED THIS LINE
         return false;
     }
 return true;  }
```